# Could not find file or assembly. An attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, .net-assembly

I have a .Net windows application with N number of projects and class libraries projects.
They all are using reference of each other.

At the time of running my setup, I am getting an issue in the middle of installation as described below:

Could not find file or assembly "`My one Project`". `Version=1.0.0.0`, `Culture=neutral`, `PublicKeyToken=80955c93367666f4` or one of its dependencies.
An attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format

*A detailed error of Fusion log is shown below:-*

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\JohnDoe\Foo\Foo.InstallUtil.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = FBFDEV\Anon.User
LOG: DisplayName = Foo.Setup, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=80955c93367666f4
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/JohnDoe/Foo/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\JohnDoe\Foo\Foo.InstallUtil.exe.Config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/JohnDoe/Foo/Foo.Setup.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files (x86)\JohnDoe\Foo\Foo.Setup.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Foo.Setup, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=80955c93367666f4
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: The fusion log shows a plain DLL Hell problem, your program is looking for version 1.0.0.0 but it found version 2.0.0.0.  You'll have to deploy the correct version of the assembly or rebuild your program to work with the new version.  Which probably means you'll have to target .NET version 4.

Comment: Thank u , It little bit resolve my issue but i got another issue after that.